# Calling an Excel formula from server-side Ruby web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openoffice.org, excel-formula

My customer has a coded a function that takes 20 boolean values and comes up with an integer result.

They did it with Excel, as a complex formula.

In a new ROR web application, am I better off recoding the whole thing in Ruby, or somehow calling the Excel formula?

I could try to contact a server-side instance of Excel or headless OpenOffice and communicate with it using [JACOB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/) or the [OpenOffice API](http://api.openoffice.org/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the spreadsheet gem to read from the Excel file. Try the following code, using a sample file in the same directory called ss.xls which has 1 in A1, 2 in B1, and =A1+B1 in C1.

```
#gem install spreadsheet

require 'spreadsheet'    
book = Spreadsheet.open('ss.xls')
sheet = book.worksheet('Sheet1')
puts sheet.row(0)[2].value
```

The `value` call returns the last value for the cell that was calculated by Excel, with the above example it will output `3.0`

Edit: Read more about the gem here: http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_txt.html

Edit 2: Of course, if you happen to be on Windows you will not need a gem; you just can use the win32ole library as described here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/win32.html

Comment: It certainly does not evaluate `TODAY()` and `NOW()`. It simply outputs the last calculated value as it was in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

No answers, so for now I will guess that re-implementing the formula in Ruby is less difficult than calling Excel/OpenOffice.

Feel free to provide a better answer!

Comment: If you could run python in your server, you could use `xlwt.Formula` to parse excel formulas.